# Delegate to property

Tags: c#, properties, delegates

I would like to get a delegate to a property´s set function. This is how I do today:

```
var property = typeof(IApplicationState).GetProperty(propertyName);
var action = (Action<IApplicationState, T>)Delegate.CreateDelegate(typeof(Action<IApplicationState, T>), null, property.GetSetMethod());
```

This works, but then I have know the name of the property.

Can I do this without using the name? Something like this:

```
var action = (Action<IApplicationState, T>)Delegate.CreateDelegate(typeof(Action<IApplicationState, T>), null, IApplicationState.PROPERTY.GetSetMethod());
```

Comment: possible duplicate of [Create a delegate from a property getter or setter method](http://stackoverflow.com/questions/2621488/create-a-delegate-from-a-property-getter-or-setter-method)

Answer (score 4, accepted):

One simple option which does introduce an extra hop (but would probably have negligible performance impact) would be to just use a lambda expression:

```
Action<IApplicationState, T> action = (state, value) => state.Foo = value;
```

There's currently no way of referring to a property at compile-time in the same way as we can refer to a type with `typeof` - although it's on the C# team's feature request list.

EDIT: If this is in a generic method (with a type parameter of `T`), it's not at all clear to me that you'll be able to use this directly, as `state.Foo` would presumably have to be of type `T` (or `object` perhaps). We can't really help with that aspect without more context of what you're trying to achieve.

Comment: thank you Jon, can you give an example how to call the action variable

Comment: @Merni: The same way you would with your existing code - it's just a delegate. All I've suggested is a different way of creating the delegate. It's not clear what `T` is here, by the way, or what the type of the property is. I'll edit to mention that.

Comment: @Merni Just use `action(arg1, arg2)` ; it's regular delegate invocation.

Comment: Is `typeof` operator compile time? I think it returns an instance of `RuntimeType` isn't it runtime? Am I misssing anything?

Comment: @SriramSakthivel: It expresses a dependency which is checked at compile-time, so it's refactoring-safe etc. Compare that with `Type.GetType(name)` which is *entirely* execution-time. That's what I mean.

Comment: Jon I can't follow you still, can you pls give some example for what you mean compile time?

Comment: @SriramSakthivel: Try doing `typeof(FooThatDoesntExist)` - it won't compile. When it *will* compile, the generated IL will refer to a type in the same way that (say) a local variable etc would - you end up with IL for type references.