# Type-safe delegate to property getter

Tags: vb.net, delegates, compile-time, typechecking

Suppose I have this simple class:

```
Public Class Person
    Public Property Name() As String
    Public Property Married() As Boolean
End Class
```

I want to create a delegate to its property getters. After a bit of search, including [this](https://stackoverflow.com/questions/2621488/create-a-delegate-from-a-property-getter-or-setter-method?rq=1), I've written this code in VB.NET:

```
Dim p As New Person()
p.Name = "Joe"
p.Married = True

Dim propGetter1 As Func(Of Boolean) = Function() p.Married
Dim propGetter2 As Func(Of String) = Function() p.Name
```

And retrieve the value of the properties as follows:

```
Dim married as Boolean = propGetter1.Invoke
Dim name as String = propGetter2.Invoke
```

It works fine, but contrary to the example in C# from the link above, it does not check at compile-time the type returned by the Function, so I could just write this code:

```
Dim propGetter1 As Func(Of Boolean) = Function() p.Name
```

Getting an error at runtime.

I've also tried this code:

```
Dim propGetter3 As Func(Of String) = Function(p As Person) p.Name
```

But I get the following error:

*Nested function does not have a signature that is compatible with delegate 'System.Func(Of Boolean)'*

So, how can I write this delegates with type-checking at compile-time, just like in C#??

**EDIT:**

As I've been asked to do so, I explain what I'm trying to do with this approach. I have an application that reads the state of a system (probe mesures, flows, preassures...) each few seconds, and stores this information in some properties of the objects that model the system.

I want to offer the user a list of all the objects defined which have properties that get their values updated this way. Therefore, the user can set alarm rules, so when a property reaches a certain value, an alarm is fired.

In orden to do so, I need to save delegates to the chosen properties, so I can check its values each few seconds, and compare them to the expected ones.
Does it make sense?

Comment: **1)** Unless your name is "True" or "False", how can a name ever be a boolean value? `Dim propGetter1 As Func(Of Boolean) = Function() p.Name` **2)** `Func(Of String)` should be `Func(Of Person, String)`

Comment: 1) I want to learn a syntax that protects me from making that kind of mistakes, I mean, assigning a Function which returns some type (i.e. String) to a delegate that expects a Function returning some other type (i.e. Boolean).
2) I want to obtain a delegate to a property setter of an instance of an object, which I can use without that object. If I declare it as you suggest, I will need to pass the object as an argument, am I rigth?

Comment: What are you trying to achieve with it? Yes, it is possible to build a spherical horse in vacuum, theoretically... Please state the original problem you are having with your code. And then point how this approach would address it.

Comment: You can use reflection to retrieve the getter/setter methods. And if you really need to get a *pointer* then you should use `Marshal.GetFunctionPointerForDelegate`.

Answer (score 4, accepted):

This is VB.NET's in/famous dynamic typing at work:

```
Option Strict Off

Module Module1
    Sub Main()
        Dim p As New Person With {.Name = "True"}
        Dim propGetter1 As Func(Of Boolean) = Function() p.Name
        Dim result = propGetter1()    '' Fine :)
    End Sub
End Module
```

If you don't like surprises like this then just use `Option Strict On` and the compiler will tell you that you got it wrong at build time.  Use Tools + Options, Projects and Solutions, VB Defaults to change the default setting.  Do beware that you might have some trouble with older projects ;)

Comment: Sorry @Hans, I don't understand your comment. Do you mean that trying to learn a syntax that protects me from making that kind of mistakes is a bad practice?

Comment: No, just pay attention to the answer please.